Create primary index for primary key in postgres with desc ordering
I have a table with time-series data and with a primary key - actually several large tables but this will do as an example:
postgres=# create table foo (x varchar, y varchar, z text, updated timestamptz, primary key(x, y, updated));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# \d foo
                         Table "public.foo"
 Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 x       | character varying        |           | not null | 
 y       | character varying        |           | not null | 
 z       | text                     |           |          | 
 updated | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:

This will automatically create an index on x, updated. However, many of my queries are looking for "the most recent foo for various values of x" not the oldest so the index is the wrong way round for efficient querying.
For example, If I do:
explain analyze select distinct on (x,y,updated) * from foo order by x,y,updated;

Then it uses the index nicely:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=0.43..145739.21 rows=158334 width=38) (actual time=0.031..889.771 rows=1583344 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo  (cost=0.43..133864.13 rows=1583344 width=38) (actual time=0.030..534.995 rows=1583344 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.074 ms
 Execution Time: 958.419 ms
(4 rows)

but of course shows me the oldest elements.
If I do:
userdb=> explain analyze select distinct on (x,y,updated) * from foo order by x, y, updated desc;
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=278945.67..294779.11 rows=158334 width=38) (actual time=3823.677..4808.844 rows=1583344 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=278945.67..282904.03 rows=1583344 width=38) (actual time=3823.674..4482.405 rows=1583344 loops=1)
         Sort Key: x, y, updated DESC
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 79536kB
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..29314.44 rows=1583344 width=38) (actual time=0.013..142.781 rows=1583344 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.075 ms
 Execution Time: 4888.878 ms
(7 rows)

then it gives me the most recent data which is what I want but takes five times as long.
What I'd like to get is this:
                         Table "public.foo"
 Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 x       | character varying        |           | not null | 
 y       | character varying        |           | not null | 
 z       | integer                  |           |          | 
 updated | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (x, y, updated DESC)

This just produces a syntax error:
create table foo (x varchar, y varchar, z text, updated timestamptz, primary key(x, y, updated desc));

I can do this:
postgres=# create index on foo (x, y, updated desc);
CREATE INDEX
postgres=#

which fixes the query but then I get two indices which is obviously less performant than one. I can drop the primary key but that feels pretty ugly. Is there a better way to get what I want? Is there a good reason why a PK generates an index with particular ordering and why that ordering being the other way round would be be problematic?
The only references I can see elsewhere are a thread (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5afb04860910140012g79755d53t9eab8de2fc2bb1b3@mail.gmail.com) which suggests that a unique index and no PK is the best option but that's 15 years old. Is there anything better now?
i.e. Is this really the best I can do?
=> alter table foo drop constraint foo_pkey;
ALTER TABLE
=> create unique index on foo(x,y,updated desc);
CREATE INDEX
=> explain analyze select distinct on (x,y,updated) * from foo order by x, y, updated desc;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=0.43..126019.21 rows=158334 width=38) (actual time=0.025..867.984 rows=1583344 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using foo_x_y_updated_idx on foo  (cost=0.43..114144.13 rows=1583344 width=38) (actual time=0.024..521.720 rows=1583344 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.171 ms
 Execution Time: 935.838 ms
(4 rows)


Because CREATE TABLE: The PRIMARY KEY constraint specifies that a column or columns of a table can contain only unique (non-duplicate), nonnull values. and Adding a PRIMARY KEY constraint will automatically create a unique btree index. So a PK is constraint not an index, though it does have a generic index created on it. If you want something less generic  then you will need to create a specific index on the columns.

unique index and no PK is the best option ... Is there anything better now? Nope, still valid and for what you want the best.

What problem should it solve? And why can't your current query pick the correct query plan? Please share the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this SQL statement and the statement itself.

@AdrianKlaver Yes, my question is if I can force it to use a different index to do the same job and it sounds from Belayer as if the answer is still no.


It is easy enough to test, run the query using EXPLAIN ANALYZE without and with create index on foo (x, updated desc); and see what the results are? 2) Per @FrankHeikens comment you should do that with your current setup and add results, as text, to your question text.


Have you compared the performance with (x, updated) vs. (x, updated DESC) using the actual queries, or are the concerns just conjecture? There might be a performance difference if DISTINCT ON (x) ... ORDER BY x, updated DESC is used to determine the most recently updated for each x; however, SELECT x, MAX(updated) ... GROUP BY x is likely to perform comparably with either option.

A primary key and an index server different purposes. The former ensures row uniqueness, while the latter can help with performant queries. In some cases one of them can server both purposes. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

What version are you using?  Having only the pk index, I get an Incremental Sort which should be pretty good.

@jjanes Aurora serverless - "PostgreSQL 14.9 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 9.5.0, 64-bit"

It looks like the ability to use Incremental Sort was not extended to DISTINCT (and apparently not to DISTINCT ON) until v16.

You cannot create a primary key with an index that sorts descending on a column.
But that may not be necessary for your use case: PostgreSQL can scan the index in descending order just as efficiently as in ascending order, so you should rewrite the query as follows:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (x, y, updated) *
FROM foo
ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC, updated DESC;

That will scan the primary key index backwards and does not require a sort.
If it is important for you that the result is sorted in ascending order for x and y, you either have to bite the bullet and create a second index, or you add another sort after the DISTINCT, which should be a bit cheaper than sorting before the DISTINCT:
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (x, y, updated) *
      FROM foo
      ORDER BY x DESC, y DESC, updated DESC
     ) AS q
ORDER BY x, y;


I've updated the question with "distinct on" examples that show this isn't necessarily true.

It is working for "explain analyze select x, y, max(updated) from foo group by 1,2;" vs. "explain analyze select x, y, min(updated) from foo group by 1,2;" and I don't really understand why the distinct on would behave so differently.

So "explain analyze select distinct on (x,y,updated) * from foo order by x desc, y desc, updated desc;" gives me an "Index Scan Backward" so this sort-of works and is good to know but the unique index option is twice as quick so that's what I'm going with. Thanks. The initial statement "You cannot create a primary key with an index that sorts descending on a column." is the correct answer (albeit one I didn't want)

Right, but I wanted to show you ways out rather than only saying "you cannot have it". DISTINCT ON works like this: The result is sorted according to ORDER BY, and for each group defined in the DISTINCT ON clause, the first result row is used. So an index can be used for DISTINCT ON if it can be used for the ORDER BY clause.
